# how to fix this prompt anaconda error msg

Tags: python, windows, prompt

I use **windows 8.1** and I tried to install **hdbscan** package `command line : pip install hdbscan`, the installation starts first normally but after I have got this msg error

any idea about how to fix it, please?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: don't post text as image

Comment: I think Marcin meant post the text from the image (the error message, which is useful for answering this question) as actual text in the question rather than as an image

Comment: I had removed it to convert it into a text but it doesn't be converted correctly and I forgot to re-upload it. Anyway I have fixed my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should download and install visual studio c++ 14.0
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Thanks Aly I install VS c++ 14.20 It works know. I don't know why It didn't work before even I had c++ 14.03!!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install hdbscan
```

[image]

My execution